# VBA check if array has a value on certain position

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array called `alterArray()` which gets filled automatically with values out of outlook (which works fine). The array has a maximum of 6 values, but sometimes the array has just 3 values (so `alterArray(0-2)` is filled with values but `alterArray(3-5)` is empty).

How can I check, if, for example, alterArray(5) has a value?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
Sub HowEmptyIsIt()
    Dim alterArray(0 To 5) As Variant
    alterArray(0) = "X"
    MsgBox IsEmpty(alterArray(5))
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

to get its *actual* dimension you could use a helper function:

```
Function GetActualDimension(arr As Variant) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    If IsEmpty(arr) Then Exit Function
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If IsEmpty(arr(i)) Then Exit For
    Next
    GetActualDimension = i - 1
End Function
```

that you could exploit in your main code as follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim alterArray As Variant

    MsgBox GetActualDimension(alterArray) '-> returns zero
    alterArray = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A4").Value) ' fill your array
    MsgBox GetActualDimension(alterArray) '-> returns "actual" size
End Sub
```